# Security of GeoServer WMS layer URL

Tags: geoserver, security

How can I secure my WMS layer URL on GeoServer as whenever a WMS layer is loaded from GeoServer than the layer URL can be easily seen in the browser console?

Comment: What about using the native geoserver security engine?

Answer (score 1):

please follow below link:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Load-GeoServer-WMS-secured-layers-with-OpenLayers-td3919938.html

It sends the request to a servlet and then redirect to geoserver